# When pouring in anti-freeze why does choking the hose allow it flow better

Tags: cooling-system

Just wondering what exactly is going on there. When I pour in antifreeze and choke the the hose the antifreeze flows a lot better through. Any idea why this is?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "choking the hose"? And which hose are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I think the hose in question is the upper radiator hose.  Squeezing the hose makes it oval shaped which makes it easier for air to escape as fluid enters.  That is, the antifreeze has to displace any air in the system and the only place for that air to escape is out through the vent cap.  Squeezing the hose just makes that easier...